# Existence of injective compact operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compactness

We know that if  $X$ is a separable Banach space, then for every infinite dimensional Banach space  $Y$, there exists an injective compact operator from $X$ to $Y$.

My query is for every  Banach space $X$ (need not be separable ) do there exist a Banach space  $Y$ and an injective compact operator  $T:X\to Y$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, for cardinality reasons. The range of a compact operator is norm-separable hence has cardinality continuum (if non-zero). It is then enough to take $X$ to have bigger cardinality, for example, $X = \ell_\infty^*$. Then you have no chance of building such operators.

Another possibility for counterexamples comes with non-separable reflexive spaces (or, more generally, WCG spaces), which contain non-separable weakly compact sets. Injective bounded linear operators are then homeomorphic embeddings of such sets with respect to the weak topology, so cannot be compact.

Comment: I was actually trying to check that it never exists if $X$ is non-separable.

Comment: @YCor, take $T\colon \ell_\infty\to c_0$ given by $T (\xi_k)_{k=1}^\infty = (\xi_k / k)_{k=1}^\infty$. It is compact and injective.

Comment: Thanks, I can see why I was stuck! In any case this provides useful context.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth pointing out that $X$ has the property if and only if $X^*$ is weak$^*$ separable, which is a somewhat weaker condition than that $X$ embeds isomorphically into $\ell_\infty$.

Comment: @BillJohnson, with the first known example being your space $J\! L$ :-)

Comment: @TamaszKania: And a better one in our recent joint paper. :-)